# one-producer and multiple consumer : should I use N semaphore if there are N consumers and N types of products

Tags: c, multithreading, algorithm, mutex, semaphore

I have a program with 1 producer thread and N consumer threads. There are N types of producet, so I set up N FIFO queues(products should be delivered to the consumer in sequence). like: FIFO_queue_t* fifo_queque[N].

The consumer threads are blocked/waiting if there are no products on its FIFO queue.
So for consumer thread `i`, they do:

```
        for(;;)
        {
            sem_wait(&sem[i]);
            product = fetch_one_product(queue);
            process(product);
         }
```

and for the producer, it call sem_post(&semp[i]) when it put a product for thread `i` into FIFO queue `i`.

it seems to me that I have to use N semaphores in this case, and if N is big, the resource consumption is big.  is there anything missing in my thinking?

**Update**:

```
 The system is like a proxy, and my original design is like this:
```

I have a tcp server listening on a port, `listen(listenfd, 20)`;

The producer is a libpcap instance, which capture TCP packets from that port, the products are the capture packets(including IP/TCP header);

For each connfd=accept(listenfd). I create a thread responsible for this connfd. These threads are consumers.

I create a lookup table, the fields in each entry are:

```
1 source IP/PORT, source address of incoming TCP connection,
2 FIFO Queue pointer: the fifo queue of captured spacket
3 pthread id :  the thread that is responsible for a tcp connection
```

when a producer thread fetch a packet, it parse the source IP/PORT from the packet, lookup the table, locate the FIFO queue and put it in the FIFO queue.

when a consumer thread gets notified that there are some packets in its FIFO queue, it fetches packets from the queue. And especially, for the intial 3-way packets: TCP SYN, SYN/ACK and ACK, it needs to maintain some states information, like MSS, SACK, etc.
And it also needs put these packets(including TCP/IP header) as UDP payload, and send UDP packets to some other remote hosts.

Comment: Are your consumer threads really different processes?  If your threads are actually pthreads then use `pthread_mutex` and `pthread_condition_variable`.  They don't allow interprocess synchronization, but consume much less resources (just some memory and a `futex`.)  If your threads are all in different processes then you will need to use semaphores.

Comment: then I still need to use N pairs of `pthread_mutex` and `pthread_condition_variable`, isn' it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a design that isn't going to scale well. If you have 1,000 different products, then you'll have 1,000 different FIFO queues, 1,000 semaphores, and 1,000 threads running. This is going to be nearly impossible to manage.

You'd be better off with a single queue and a small number of threads. The threads can handle any type of item. Your only difficulty will be delivering items to the customer in order, but that won't *normally* be a problem. To solve it, all you need to do is add a sequence number of some sort so that when an item is about to be sent to the customer, you check the sequence number and wait if it's not the one you expect.

You don't actually wait, of course, but rather put the item into an output queue that is blocked, waiting for the correct item to come in. This works well if you can guarantee that a thread won't crash and drop an item. Because if that happens, output to your customer is going to stop. You need some sort of policy that will prevent a permanent block: perhaps a timeout that says, "Well, I waited long enough. Customer is going to get this item even though it's out of order."

Added in response to comment:

So you have a single input queue filled by the producer, a small number of consumer threads, each of which can process any type of product, and then either N output queues (which seems excessive), or a single output queue with overflow to allow for buffering out-of-order items. I'll assume that you have a small number of threads (perhaps only one?) servicing the output queues and sending items to the customers.

Items that come out of order should only stay in the overflow for a very brief time. They are there because two (or more) items of the same type were dequeued very close together, and the latter one got finished processing before the earlier one(s). This should be a rare event, so your overflow bucket shouldn't be very large at all. You could easily make the overflow a simple list, and scan it sequentially with no noticeable performance penalty.

Comment: Also: given this solution two threads can now be working on the same type of product simultaneously.  So you may need some (scalable) way of putting `process(product)` in a critical section.

Comment: even if I make several threads, there are still N types of products. For different products, I have different processings, i.e, I need to deliver them to N different remote hosts.

Comment: @misteryes: See my additional info.

Comment: hi, I have updated some details of my system. iS the design idea of your comment suitable for my system or not? I can't adapt it to my system.